# ouput boolean value in join query if conditions are met

Tags: join, boolean

here is what i would like to accomplish: I have two (or more) tables in join, and I would like to get a boolean output if some conditions are met, e.g.

Table1:

| customer_id | customer_name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Google | waiting |
| 2 | Facebook | working |
| 3 | Salesforce | waiting |

Table2:

| customer_id | agent | outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | failure |
| 1 | Mike | success |
| 2 | John | success |

I would like to get for all customer ids true if status in Table1  is "waiting" and there is no Table2 record for that customer

Desired output:

| customer_id | waiting_and_no_record_in_table_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | false |
| 2 | false |
| 3 | true |

Any idea on how to reach this goal?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As there can be multiple rows per customer_id in table2, to achieve the desired result requires some simplification be applied on table2. For this I simply chose `select distinct` which is sufficient for the example, but alternatives do exist.

```
select
  table1.customer_id
, case when table1.status = 'waiting' and t2.customer_id IS NULL then true else false end as waiting_and_no_record_in_table_2
from table1
left join (select distinct customer_id from table2) as t2 on table1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
order by 
  table1.customer_id
```

and alternative might be to join only successful rows from t2 although this may still produce more than one row per customer_id

```
select
  table1.customer_id
, case when table1.status = 'waiting' and t2.customer_id IS NULL then true else false end as waiting_and_no_record_in_table_2
from table1
left join table2 as t2 on table1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
                      and t2.outcome = 'success'
order by 
  table1.customer_id
```

or these 2 might be combined to also ensure only one row per customer_id

```
select
  table1.customer_id
, case when table1.status = 'waiting' and t2.customer_id IS NULL then true else false end as waiting_and_no_record_in_table_2
from table1
left join (select distinct customer_id from table2 where outcome = 'success') as t2 on table1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
order by 
  table1.customer_id
```